# Combining three states into one round in AES decryption

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am writing a program about AES encryption.

To get a faster speed for AES encryption and decryption, three states of AES (sub byte, shift row, and mix column) can be combined into one round state.

I can successfully combine these three states into one round in AES encryption (it can decrypt with original flow AES decryption) but for AES decryption I can't get the original  data.

I think it's because of the flow of decryption. In decryption, shift row and sub byte do first and followed by add round and mix column. So, shift row, sub byte and mix column is not continuous.

My code is here:

```
"""Tham module provides encrypting/decrypting according AES(128) standard. 
Based on Rijndael algorithm, AES uses 4 transformation for encrypting: SubSytes(), ShiftRows(),
MixColumns() and AddRoundKey(). For decrypting it uses inverse functions of that fout.
Detales you can read here:
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf
or here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard
or here:
http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/cs381-05/blockciphers/rijndael_ingles2004.swf
or somewhere else.

Comments rather won't help if don't read documentation of the algorithm.

"""

nb = 4  # number of column of State (for AES = 4)
nr = 14  # number of rounds ib cipher cycle (if nb = 4 nr = 10)
nk = 8  # the key length (in 32-bit words)

# This dict will be used in SubBytes(). 
hex_symbols_to_int = {'a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 12, 'd': 13, 'e': 14, 'f': 15}

sbox = [
    0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
    0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
    0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
    0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
    0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
    0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
    0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
    0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
    0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
    0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
    0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
    0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08,
    0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a,
    0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
    0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
    0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
]

inv_sbox = [
    0x52, 0x09, 0x6a, 0xd5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xa5, 0x38, 0xbf, 0x40, 0xa3, 0x9e, 0x81, 0xf3, 0xd7, 0xfb,
    0x7c, 0xe3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9b, 0x2f, 0xff, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8e, 0x43, 0x44, 0xc4, 0xde, 0xe9, 0xcb,
    0x54, 0x7b, 0x94, 0x32, 0xa6, 0xc2, 0x23, 0x3d, 0xee, 0x4c, 0x95, 0x0b, 0x42, 0xfa, 0xc3, 0x4e,
    0x08, 0x2e, 0xa1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xd9, 0x24, 0xb2, 0x76, 0x5b, 0xa2, 0x49, 0x6d, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0x25,
    0x72, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xd4, 0xa4, 0x5c, 0xcc, 0x5d, 0x65, 0xb6, 0x92,
    0x6c, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xfd, 0xed, 0xb9, 0xda, 0x5e, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xa7, 0x8d, 0x9d, 0x84,
    0x90, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x00, 0x8c, 0xbc, 0xd3, 0x0a, 0xf7, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xb8, 0xb3, 0x45, 0x06,
    0xd0, 0x2c, 0x1e, 0x8f, 0xca, 0x3f, 0x0f, 0x02, 0xc1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8a, 0x6b,
    0x3a, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xea, 0x97, 0xf2, 0xcf, 0xce, 0xf0, 0xb4, 0xe6, 0x73,
    0x96, 0xac, 0x74, 0x22, 0xe7, 0xad, 0x35, 0x85, 0xe2, 0xf9, 0x37, 0xe8, 0x1c, 0x75, 0xdf, 0x6e,
    0x47, 0xf1, 0x1a, 0x71, 0x1d, 0x29, 0xc5, 0x89, 0x6f, 0xb7, 0x62, 0x0e, 0xaa, 0x18, 0xbe, 0x1b,
    0xfc, 0x56, 0x3e, 0x4b, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9a, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0x78, 0xcd, 0x5a, 0xf4,
    0x1f, 0xdd, 0xa8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xc7, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xec, 0x5f,
    0x60, 0x51, 0x7f, 0xa9, 0x19, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0x0d, 0x2d, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0x9f, 0x93, 0xc9, 0x9c, 0xef,
    0xa0, 0xe0, 0x3b, 0x4d, 0xae, 0x2a, 0xf5, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0xeb, 0xbb, 0x3c, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61,
    0x17, 0x2b, 0x04, 0x7e, 0xba, 0x77, 0xd6, 0x26, 0xe1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x7d
]

rcon = [[0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d],
        [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
        [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
        [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
]

Xtime2Sbox = [
0xc6, 0xf8, 0xee, 0xf6, 0xff, 0xd6, 0xde, 0x91, 0x60, 0x02, 0xce, 0x56, 0xe7, 0xb5, 0x4d, 0xec,
0x8f, 0x1f, 0x89, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xb2, 0x8e, 0xfb, 0x41, 0xb3, 0x5f, 0x45, 0x23, 0x53, 0xe4, 0x9b,
0x75, 0xe1, 0x3d, 0x4c, 0x6c, 0x7e, 0xf5, 0x83, 0x68, 0x51, 0xd1, 0xf9, 0xe2, 0xab, 0x62, 0x2a,
0x08, 0x95, 0x46, 0x9d, 0x30, 0x37, 0x0a, 0x2f, 0x0e, 0x24, 0x1b, 0xdf, 0xcd, 0x4e, 0x7f, 0xea,
0x12, 0x1d, 0x58, 0x34, 0x36, 0xdc, 0xb4, 0x5b, 0xa4, 0x76, 0xb7, 0x7d, 0x52, 0xdd, 0x5e, 0x13,
0xa6, 0xb9, 0x00, 0xc1, 0x40, 0xe3, 0x79, 0xb6, 0xd4, 0x8d, 0x67, 0x72, 0x94, 0x98, 0xb0, 0x85,
0xbb, 0xc5, 0x4f, 0xed, 0x86, 0x9a, 0x66, 0x11, 0x8a, 0xe9, 0x04, 0xfe, 0xa0, 0x78, 0x25, 0x4b,
0xa2, 0x5d, 0x80, 0x05, 0x3f, 0x21, 0x70, 0xf1, 0x63, 0x77, 0xaf, 0x42, 0x20, 0xe5, 0xfd, 0xbf,
0x81, 0x18, 0x26, 0xc3, 0xbe, 0x35, 0x88, 0x2e, 0x93, 0x55, 0xfc, 0x7a, 0xc8, 0xba, 0x32, 0xe6,
0xc0, 0x19, 0x9e, 0xa3, 0x44, 0x54, 0x3b, 0x0b, 0x8c, 0xc7, 0x6b, 0x28, 0xa7, 0xbc, 0x16, 0xad,
0xdb, 0x64, 0x74, 0x14, 0x92, 0x0c, 0x48, 0xb8, 0x9f, 0xbd, 0x43, 0xc4, 0x39, 0x31, 0xd3, 0xf2,
0xd5, 0x8b, 0x6e, 0xda, 0x01, 0xb1, 0x9c, 0x49, 0xd8, 0xac, 0xf3, 0xcf, 0xca, 0xf4, 0x47, 0x10,
0x6f, 0xf0, 0x4a, 0x5c, 0x38, 0x57, 0x73, 0x97, 0xcb, 0xa1, 0xe8, 0x3e, 0x96, 0x61, 0x0d, 0x0f,
0xe0, 0x7c, 0x71, 0xcc, 0x90, 0x06, 0xf7, 0x1c, 0xc2, 0x6a, 0xae, 0x69, 0x17, 0x99, 0x3a, 0x27,
0xd9, 0xeb, 0x2b, 0x22, 0xd2, 0xa9, 0x07, 0x33, 0x2d, 0x3c, 0x15, 0xc9, 0x87, 0xaa, 0x50, 0xa5,
0x03, 0x59, 0x09, 0x1a, 0x65, 0xd7, 0x84, 0xd0, 0x82, 0x29, 0x5a, 0x1e, 0x7b, 0xa8, 0x6d, 0x2c
]


Xtime3Sbox = [
0xa5, 0x84, 0x99, 0x8d, 0x0d, 0xbd, 0xb1, 0x54, 0x50, 0x03, 0xa9, 0x7d, 0x19, 0x62, 0xe6, 0x9a,
0x45, 0x9d, 0x40, 0x87, 0x15, 0xeb, 0xc9, 0x0b, 0xec, 0x67, 0xfd, 0xea, 0xbf, 0xf7, 0x96, 0x5b,
0xc2, 0x1c, 0xae, 0x6a, 0x5a, 0x41, 0x02, 0x4f, 0x5c, 0xf4, 0x34, 0x08, 0x93, 0x73, 0x53, 0x3f,
0x0c, 0x52, 0x65, 0x5e, 0x28, 0xa1, 0x0f, 0xb5, 0x09, 0x36, 0x9b, 0x3d, 0x26, 0x69, 0xcd, 0x9f,
0x1b, 0x9e, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x2d, 0xb2, 0xee, 0xfb, 0xf6, 0x4d, 0x61, 0xce, 0x7b, 0x3e, 0x71, 0x97,
0xf5, 0x68, 0x00, 0x2c, 0x60, 0x1f, 0xc8, 0xed, 0xbe, 0x46, 0xd9, 0x4b, 0xde, 0xd4, 0xe8, 0x4a,
0x6b, 0x2a, 0xe5, 0x16, 0xc5, 0xd7, 0x55, 0x94, 0xcf, 0x10, 0x06, 0x81, 0xf0, 0x44, 0xba, 0xe3,
0xf3, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0x8a, 0xad, 0xbc, 0x48, 0x04, 0xdf, 0xc1, 0x75, 0x63, 0x30, 0x1a, 0x0e, 0x6d,
0x4c, 0x14, 0x35, 0x2f, 0xe1, 0xa2, 0xcc, 0x39, 0x57, 0xf2, 0x82, 0x47, 0xac, 0xe7, 0x2b, 0x95,
0xa0, 0x98, 0xd1, 0x7f, 0x66, 0x7e, 0xab, 0x83, 0xca, 0x29, 0xd3, 0x3c, 0x79, 0xe2, 0x1d, 0x76,
0x3b, 0x56, 0x4e, 0x1e, 0xdb, 0x0a, 0x6c, 0xe4, 0x5d, 0x6e, 0xef, 0xa6, 0xa8, 0xa4, 0x37, 0x8b,
0x32, 0x43, 0x59, 0xb7, 0x8c, 0x64, 0xd2, 0xe0, 0xb4, 0xfa, 0x07, 0x25, 0xaf, 0x8e, 0xe9, 0x18,
0xd5, 0x88, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x24, 0xf1, 0xc7, 0x51, 0x23, 0x7c, 0x9c, 0x21, 0xdd, 0xdc, 0x86, 0x85,
0x90, 0x42, 0xc4, 0xaa, 0xd8, 0x05, 0x01, 0x12, 0xa3, 0x5f, 0xf9, 0xd0, 0x91, 0x58, 0x27, 0xb9,
0x38, 0x13, 0xb3, 0x33, 0xbb, 0x70, 0x89, 0xa7, 0xb6, 0x22, 0x92, 0x20, 0x49, 0xff, 0x78, 0x7a,
0x8f, 0xf8, 0x80, 0x17, 0xda, 0x31, 0xc6, 0xb8, 0xc3, 0xb0, 0x77, 0x11, 0xcb, 0xfc, 0xd6, 0x3a
]

Xtime2 = [
0x00,0x02,0x04,0x06,0x08,0x0a,0x0c,0x0e,0x10,0x12,0x14,0x16,0x18,0x1a,0x1c,0x1e,
0x20,0x22,0x24,0x26,0x28,0x2a,0x2c,0x2e,0x30,0x32,0x34,0x36,0x38,0x3a,0x3c,0x3e,
0x40,0x42,0x44,0x46,0x48,0x4a,0x4c,0x4e,0x50,0x52,0x54,0x56,0x58,0x5a,0x5c,0x5e,
0x60,0x62,0x64,0x66,0x68,0x6a,0x6c,0x6e,0x70,0x72,0x74,0x76,0x78,0x7a,0x7c,0x7e,
0x80,0x82,0x84,0x86,0x88,0x8a,0x8c,0x8e,0x90,0x92,0x94,0x96,0x98,0x9a,0x9c,0x9e,
0xa0,0xa2,0xa4,0xa6,0xa8,0xaa,0xac,0xae,0xb0,0xb2,0xb4,0xb6,0xb8,0xba,0xbc,0xbe,
0xc0,0xc2,0xc4,0xc6,0xc8,0xca,0xcc,0xce,0xd0,0xd2,0xd4,0xd6,0xd8,0xda,0xdc,0xde,
0xe0,0xe2,0xe4,0xe6,0xe8,0xea,0xec,0xee,0xf0,0xf2,0xf4,0xf6,0xf8,0xfa,0xfc,0xfe,
0x1b,0x19,0x1f,0x1d,0x13,0x11,0x17,0x15,0x0b,0x09,0x0f,0x0d,0x03,0x01,0x07,0x05,
0x3b,0x39,0x3f,0x3d,0x33,0x31,0x37,0x35,0x2b,0x29,0x2f,0x2d,0x23,0x21,0x27,0x25,
0x5b,0x59,0x5f,0x5d,0x53,0x51,0x57,0x55,0x4b,0x49,0x4f,0x4d,0x43,0x41,0x47,0x45,
0x7b,0x79,0x7f,0x7d,0x73,0x71,0x77,0x75,0x6b,0x69,0x6f,0x6d,0x63,0x61,0x67,0x65,
0x9b,0x99,0x9f,0x9d,0x93,0x91,0x97,0x95,0x8b,0x89,0x8f,0x8d,0x83,0x81,0x87,0x85,
0xbb,0xb9,0xbf,0xbd,0xb3,0xb1,0xb7,0xb5,0xab,0xa9,0xaf,0xad,0xa3,0xa1,0xa7,0xa5,
0xdb,0xd9,0xdf,0xdd,0xd3,0xd1,0xd7,0xd5,0xcb,0xc9,0xcf,0xcd,0xc3,0xc1,0xc7,0xc5,
0xfb,0xf9,0xff,0xfd,0xf3,0xf1,0xf7,0xf5,0xeb,0xe9,0xef,0xed,0xe3,0xe1,0xe7,0xe5
]

Xtime3  = [
0x00,0x03,0x06,0x05,0x0c,0x0f,0x0a,0x09,0x18,0x1b,0x1e,0x1d,0x14,0x17,0x12,0x11,
0x30,0x33,0x36,0x35,0x3c,0x3f,0x3a,0x39,0x28,0x2b,0x2e,0x2d,0x24,0x27,0x22,0x21,
0x60,0x63,0x66,0x65,0x6c,0x6f,0x6a,0x69,0x78,0x7b,0x7e,0x7d,0x74,0x77,0x72,0x71,
0x50,0x53,0x56,0x55,0x5c,0x5f,0x5a,0x59,0x48,0x4b,0x4e,0x4d,0x44,0x47,0x42,0x41,
0xc0,0xc3,0xc6,0xc5,0xcc,0xcf,0xca,0xc9,0xd8,0xdb,0xde,0xdd,0xd4,0xd7,0xd2,0xd1,
0xf0,0xf3,0xf6,0xf5,0xfc,0xff,0xfa,0xf9,0xe8,0xeb,0xee,0xed,0xe4,0xe7,0xe2,0xe1,
0xa0,0xa3,0xa6,0xa5,0xac,0xaf,0xaa,0xa9,0xb8,0xbb,0xbe,0xbd,0xb4,0xb7,0xb2,0xb1,
0x90,0x93,0x96,0x95,0x9c,0x9f,0x9a,0x99,0x88,0x8b,0x8e,0x8d,0x84,0x87,0x82,0x81,
0x9b,0x98,0x9d,0x9e,0x97,0x94,0x91,0x92,0x83,0x80,0x85,0x86,0x8f,0x8c,0x89,0x8a,
0xab,0xa8,0xad,0xae,0xa7,0xa4,0xa1,0xa2,0xb3,0xb0,0xb5,0xb6,0xbf,0xbc,0xb9,0xba,
0xfb,0xf8,0xfd,0xfe,0xf7,0xf4,0xf1,0xf2,0xe3,0xe0,0xe5,0xe6,0xef,0xec,0xe9,0xea,
0xcb,0xc8,0xcd,0xce,0xc7,0xc4,0xc1,0xc2,0xd3,0xd0,0xd5,0xd6,0xdf,0xdc,0xd9,0xda,
0x5b,0x58,0x5d,0x5e,0x57,0x54,0x51,0x52,0x43,0x40,0x45,0x46,0x4f,0x4c,0x49,0x4a,
0x6b,0x68,0x6d,0x6e,0x67,0x64,0x61,0x62,0x73,0x70,0x75,0x76,0x7f,0x7c,0x79,0x7a,
0x3b,0x38,0x3d,0x3e,0x37,0x34,0x31,0x32,0x23,0x20,0x25,0x26,0x2f,0x2c,0x29,0x2a,
0x0b,0x08,0x0d,0x0e,0x07,0x04,0x01,0x02,0x13,0x10,0x15,0x16,0x1f,0x1c,0x19,0x1a
]

Xtime9 = [
0x00,0x09,0x12,0x1b,0x24,0x2d,0x36,0x3f,0x48,0x41,0x5a,0x53,0x6c,0x65,0x7e,0x77,
0x90,0x99,0x82,0x8b,0xb4,0xbd,0xa6,0xaf,0xd8,0xd1,0xca,0xc3,0xfc,0xf5,0xee,0xe7,
0x3b,0x32,0x29,0x20,0x1f,0x16,0x0d,0x04,0x73,0x7a,0x61,0x68,0x57,0x5e,0x45,0x4c,
0xab,0xa2,0xb9,0xb0,0x8f,0x86,0x9d,0x94,0xe3,0xea,0xf1,0xf8,0xc7,0xce,0xd5,0xdc,
0x76,0x7f,0x64,0x6d,0x52,0x5b,0x40,0x49,0x3e,0x37,0x2c,0x25,0x1a,0x13,0x08,0x01,
0xe6,0xef,0xf4,0xfd,0xc2,0xcb,0xd0,0xd9,0xae,0xa7,0xbc,0xb5,0x8a,0x83,0x98,0x91,
0x4d,0x44,0x5f,0x56,0x69,0x60,0x7b,0x72,0x05,0x0c,0x17,0x1e,0x21,0x28,0x33,0x3a,
0xdd,0xd4,0xcf,0xc6,0xf9,0xf0,0xeb,0xe2,0x95,0x9c,0x87,0x8e,0xb1,0xb8,0xa3,0xaa,
0xec,0xe5,0xfe,0xf7,0xc8,0xc1,0xda,0xd3,0xa4,0xad,0xb6,0xbf,0x80,0x89,0x92,0x9b,
0x7c,0x75,0x6e,0x67,0x58,0x51,0x4a,0x43,0x34,0x3d,0x26,0x2f,0x10,0x19,0x02,0x0b,
0xd7,0xde,0xc5,0xcc,0xf3,0xfa,0xe1,0xe8,0x9f,0x96,0x8d,0x84,0xbb,0xb2,0xa9,0xa0,
0x47,0x4e,0x55,0x5c,0x63,0x6a,0x71,0x78,0x0f,0x06,0x1d,0x14,0x2b,0x22,0x39,0x30,
0x9a,0x93,0x88,0x81,0xbe,0xb7,0xac,0xa5,0xd2,0xdb,0xc0,0xc9,0xf6,0xff,0xe4,0xed,
0x0a,0x03,0x18,0x11,0x2e,0x27,0x3c,0x35,0x42,0x4b,0x50,0x59,0x66,0x6f,0x74,0x7d,
0xa1,0xa8,0xb3,0xba,0x85,0x8c,0x97,0x9e,0xe9,0xe0,0xfb,0xf2,0xcd,0xc4,0xdf,0xd6,
0x31,0x38,0x23,0x2a,0x15,0x1c,0x07,0x0e,0x79,0x70,0x6b,0x62,0x5d,0x54,0x4f,0x46]

Xtime11=[
0x00,0x0b,0x16,0x1d,0x2c,0x27,0x3a,0x31,0x58,0x53,0x4e,0x45,0x74,0x7f,0x62,0x69,
0xb0,0xbb,0xa6,0xad,0x9c,0x97,0x8a,0x81,0xe8,0xe3,0xfe,0xf5,0xc4,0xcf,0xd2,0xd9,
0x7b,0x70,0x6d,0x66,0x57,0x5c,0x41,0x4a,0x23,0x28,0x35,0x3e,0x0f,0x04,0x19,0x12,
0xcb,0xc0,0xdd,0xd6,0xe7,0xec,0xf1,0xfa,0x93,0x98,0x85,0x8e,0xbf,0xb4,0xa9,0xa2,
0xf6,0xfd,0xe0,0xeb,0xda,0xd1,0xcc,0xc7,0xae,0xa5,0xb8,0xb3,0x82,0x89,0x94,0x9f,
0x46,0x4d,0x50,0x5b,0x6a,0x61,0x7c,0x77,0x1e,0x15,0x08,0x03,0x32,0x39,0x24,0x2f,
0x8d,0x86,0x9b,0x90,0xa1,0xaa,0xb7,0xbc,0xd5,0xde,0xc3,0xc8,0xf9,0xf2,0xef,0xe4,
0x3d,0x36,0x2b,0x20,0x11,0x1a,0x07,0x0c,0x65,0x6e,0x73,0x78,0x49,0x42,0x5f,0x54,
0xf7,0xfc,0xe1,0xea,0xdb,0xd0,0xcd,0xc6,0xaf,0xa4,0xb9,0xb2,0x83,0x88,0x95,0x9e,
0x47,0x4c,0x51,0x5a,0x6b,0x60,0x7d,0x76,0x1f,0x14,0x09,0x02,0x33,0x38,0x25,0x2e,
0x8c,0x87,0x9a,0x91,0xa0,0xab,0xb6,0xbd,0xd4,0xdf,0xc2,0xc9,0xf8,0xf3,0xee,0xe5,
0x3c,0x37,0x2a,0x21,0x10,0x1b,0x06,0x0d,0x64,0x6f,0x72,0x79,0x48,0x43,0x5e,0x55,
0x01,0x0a,0x17,0x1c,0x2d,0x26,0x3b,0x30,0x59,0x52,0x4f,0x44,0x75,0x7e,0x63,0x68,
0xb1,0xba,0xa7,0xac,0x9d,0x96,0x8b,0x80,0xe9,0xe2,0xff,0xf4,0xc5,0xce,0xd3,0xd8,
0x7a,0x71,0x6c,0x67,0x56,0x5d,0x40,0x4b,0x22,0x29,0x34,0x3f,0x0e,0x05,0x18,0x13,
0xca,0xc1,0xdc,0xd7,0xe6,0xed,0xf0,0xfb,0x92,0x99,0x84,0x8f,0xbe,0xb5,0xa8,0xa3
]

Xtime13 = [
0x00,0x0d,0x1a,0x17,0x34,0x39,0x2e,0x23,0x68,0x65,0x72,0x7f,0x5c,0x51,0x46,0x4b,
0xd0,0xdd,0xca,0xc7,0xe4,0xe9,0xfe,0xf3,0xb8,0xb5,0xa2,0xaf,0x8c,0x81,0x96,0x9b,
0xbb,0xb6,0xa1,0xac,0x8f,0x82,0x95,0x98,0xd3,0xde,0xc9,0xc4,0xe7,0xea,0xfd,0xf0,
0x6b,0x66,0x71,0x7c,0x5f,0x52,0x45,0x48,0x03,0x0e,0x19,0x14,0x37,0x3a,0x2d,0x20,
0x6d,0x60,0x77,0x7a,0x59,0x54,0x43,0x4e,0x05,0x08,0x1f,0x12,0x31,0x3c,0x2b,0x26,
0xbd,0xb0,0xa7,0xaa,0x89,0x84,0x93,0x9e,0xd5,0xd8,0xcf,0xc2,0xe1,0xec,0xfb,0xf6,
0xd6,0xdb,0xcc,0xc1,0xe2,0xef,0xf8,0xf5,0xbe,0xb3,0xa4,0xa9,0x8a,0x87,0x90,0x9d,
0x06,0x0b,0x1c,0x11,0x32,0x3f,0x28,0x25,0x6e,0x63,0x74,0x79,0x5a,0x57,0x40,0x4d,
0xda,0xd7,0xc0,0xcd,0xee,0xe3,0xf4,0xf9,0xb2,0xbf,0xa8,0xa5,0x86,0x8b,0x9c,0x91,
0x0a,0x07,0x10,0x1d,0x3e,0x33,0x24,0x29,0x62,0x6f,0x78,0x75,0x56,0x5b,0x4c,0x41,
0x61,0x6c,0x7b,0x76,0x55,0x58,0x4f,0x42,0x09,0x04,0x13,0x1e,0x3d,0x30,0x27,0x2a,
0xb1,0xbc,0xab,0xa6,0x85,0x88,0x9f,0x92,0xd9,0xd4,0xc3,0xce,0xed,0xe0,0xf7,0xfa,
0xb7,0xba,0xad,0xa0,0x83,0x8e,0x99,0x94,0xdf,0xd2,0xc5,0xc8,0xeb,0xe6,0xf1,0xfc,
0x67,0x6a,0x7d,0x70,0x53,0x5e,0x49,0x44,0x0f,0x02,0x15,0x18,0x3b,0x36,0x21,0x2c,
0x0c,0x01,0x16,0x1b,0x38,0x35,0x22,0x2f,0x64,0x69,0x7e,0x73,0x50,0x5d,0x4a,0x47,
0xdc,0xd1,0xc6,0xcb,0xe8,0xe5,0xf2,0xff,0xb4,0xb9,0xae,0xa3,0x80,0x8d,0x9a,0x97
]

Xtime14 = [
0x00,0x0e,0x1c,0x12,0x38,0x36,0x24,0x2a,0x70,0x7e,0x6c,0x62,0x48,0x46,0x54,0x5a,
0xe0,0xee,0xfc,0xf2,0xd8,0xd6,0xc4,0xca,0x90,0x9e,0x8c,0x82,0xa8,0xa6,0xb4,0xba,
0xdb,0xd5,0xc7,0xc9,0xe3,0xed,0xff,0xf1,0xab,0xa5,0xb7,0xb9,0x93,0x9d,0x8f,0x81,
0x3b,0x35,0x27,0x29,0x03,0x0d,0x1f,0x11,0x4b,0x45,0x57,0x59,0x73,0x7d,0x6f,0x61,
0xad,0xa3,0xb1,0xbf,0x95,0x9b,0x89,0x87,0xdd,0xd3,0xc1,0xcf,0xe5,0xeb,0xf9,0xf7,
0x4d,0x43,0x51,0x5f,0x75,0x7b,0x69,0x67,0x3d,0x33,0x21,0x2f,0x05,0x0b,0x19,0x17,
0x76,0x78,0x6a,0x64,0x4e,0x40,0x52,0x5c,0x06,0x08,0x1a,0x14,0x3e,0x30,0x22,0x2c,
0x96,0x98,0x8a,0x84,0xae,0xa0,0xb2,0xbc,0xe6,0xe8,0xfa,0xf4,0xde,0xd0,0xc2,0xcc,
0x41,0x4f,0x5d,0x53,0x79,0x77,0x65,0x6b,0x31,0x3f,0x2d,0x23,0x09,0x07,0x15,0x1b,
0xa1,0xaf,0xbd,0xb3,0x99,0x97,0x85,0x8b,0xd1,0xdf,0xcd,0xc3,0xe9,0xe7,0xf5,0xfb,
0x9a,0x94,0x86,0x88,0xa2,0xac,0xbe,0xb0,0xea,0xe4,0xf6,0xf8,0xd2,0xdc,0xce,0xc0,
0x7a,0x74,0x66,0x68,0x42,0x4c,0x5e,0x50,0x0a,0x04,0x16,0x18,0x32,0x3c,0x2e,0x20,
0xec,0xe2,0xf0,0xfe,0xd4,0xda,0xc8,0xc6,0x9c,0x92,0x80,0x8e,0xa4,0xaa,0xb8,0xb6,
0x0c,0x02,0x10,0x1e,0x34,0x3a,0x28,0x26,0x7c,0x72,0x60,0x6e,0x44,0x4a,0x58,0x56,
0x37,0x39,0x2b,0x25,0x0f,0x01,0x13,0x1d,0x47,0x49,0x5b,0x55,0x7f,0x71,0x63,0x6d,
0xd7,0xd9,0xcb,0xc5,0xef,0xe1,0xf3,0xfd,0xa7,0xa9,0xbb,0xb5,0x9f,0x91,0x83,0x8d
]


def encrypt(input_bytes, key):
    state = [[] for j in range(4)]  # [[],[],[],[]]
    for r in range(4):
        for c in range(nb):
            state[r].append(input_bytes[r + 4 * c])  # 4x4 list

    key_schedule = key_expansion(key)  # a list of four lists of 44 int list

    state = add_round_key(state, key_schedule)

    for rnd in range(1, nr):
        state = mixSubColumn(state)
        state = add_round_key(state, key_schedule, rnd)

    state = subshift(state)
    state = add_round_key(state, key_schedule, rnd + 1)

    output = [None for i in range(4 * nb)]
    for r in range(4):
        for c in range(nb):
            output[r + 4 * c] = state[r][c]

    return output


def decrypt(cipher, key):
    state = [[] for i in range(nb)]
    for r in range(4):
        for c in range(nb):
            state[r].append(cipher[r + 4 * c])

    key_schedule = key_expansion(key)

    state = add_round_key(state, key_schedule, nr)

    rnd = nr - 1
    while rnd >= 1:
        state = inv_subshift(state)
        state = add_round_key(state, key_schedule, rnd)
        state = mix_columns(state)

        rnd -= 1

    state = inv_subshift(state)
    state = add_round_key(state, key_schedule, rnd)

    output = [None for i in range(4 * nb)]
    for r in range(4):
        for c in range(nb):
            output[r + 4 * c] = state[r][c]

    return output


def subshift(state):
    state[0][0] = sbox[state[0][0]]
    state[0][1] = sbox[state[0][1]]
    state[0][2] = sbox[state[0][2]]
    state[0][3] = sbox[state[0][3]]

    tmp = sbox[state[1][0]]
    state[1][0] = sbox[state[1][1]]
    state[1][1] = sbox[state[1][2]]
    state[1][2] = sbox[state[1][3]]
    state[1][3] = tmp

    tmp = sbox[state[2][0]]
    state[2][0] = sbox[state[2][2]]
    state[2][2] = tmp
    tmp = sbox[state[2][1]]
    state[2][1] = sbox[state[2][3]]
    state[2][3] = tmp

    tmp = sbox[state[3][3]]
    state[3][3] = sbox[state[3][2]]
    state[3][2] = sbox[state[3][1]]
    state[3][1] = sbox[state[3][0]]
    state[3][0] = tmp

    return state

def mixSubColumn(state):

    tmp = [x[:] for x in state]

    state[0][0] = Xtime2Sbox[tmp[0][0]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[1][1]] ^ sbox[tmp[2][2]]        ^ sbox[tmp[3][3]]
    state[1][0] = sbox[tmp[0][0]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[1][1]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[2][2]] ^ sbox[tmp[3][3]]
    state[2][0] = sbox[tmp[0][0]]         ^ sbox[tmp[1][1]]       ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[2][2]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[3][3]]
    state[3][0] = Xtime3Sbox[tmp[0][0]] ^ sbox[tmp[1][1]]         ^ sbox[tmp[2][2]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[3][3]]

    state[0][1] = Xtime2Sbox[tmp[0][1]]  ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[1][2]] ^ sbox[tmp[2][3]]         ^ sbox[tmp[3][0]]
    state[1][1] = sbox[tmp[0][1]]          ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[1][2]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[2][3]] ^ sbox[tmp[3][0]]
    state[2][1] = sbox[tmp[0][1]]          ^ sbox[tmp[1][2]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[2][3]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[3][0]]
    state[3][1] = Xtime3Sbox[tmp[0][1]]  ^ sbox[tmp[1][2]]         ^ sbox[tmp[2][3]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[3][0]]

    state[0][2] = Xtime2Sbox[tmp[0][2]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[1][3]] ^ sbox[tmp[2][0]]          ^ sbox[tmp[3][1]]
    state[1][2]= sbox[tmp[0][2]]          ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[1][3]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[2][0]]  ^ sbox[tmp[3][1]]
    state[2][2] = sbox[tmp[0][2]]         ^ sbox[tmp[1][3]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[2][0]]  ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[3][1]]
    state[3][2] = Xtime3Sbox[tmp[0][2]] ^ sbox[tmp[1][3]]         ^ sbox[tmp[2][0]]          ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[3][1]]

    state[0][3] = Xtime2Sbox[tmp[0][3]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[1][0]] ^ sbox[tmp[2][1]]        ^ sbox[tmp[3][2]]
    state[1][3] = sbox[tmp[0][3]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[1][0]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[2][1]] ^ sbox[tmp[3][2]]
    state[2][3] = sbox[tmp[0][3]]         ^ sbox[tmp[1][0]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[2][1]] ^ Xtime3Sbox[tmp[3][2]]
    state[3][3] = Xtime3Sbox[tmp[0][3]] ^ sbox[tmp[1][0]]         ^ sbox[tmp[2][1]]         ^ Xtime2Sbox[tmp[3][2]]

    return state

def inv_subshift(state):

    state[0][0] = inv_sbox[state[0][0]]
    state[0][1] = inv_sbox[state[0][1]]
    state[0][2] = inv_sbox[state[0][2]]
    state[0][3] = inv_sbox[state[0][3]]

    tmp = inv_sbox[state[1][3]]
    state[1][3] = inv_sbox[state[1][2]]
    state[1][2] = inv_sbox[state[1][1]]
    state[1][1] = inv_sbox[state[1][0]]
    state[1][0] = tmp

    tmp = inv_sbox[state[2][0]]
    state[2][0] = inv_sbox[state[2][2]]
    state[2][2] = tmp
    tmp = inv_sbox[state[2][1]]
    state[2][1] = inv_sbox[state[2][3]]
    state[2][3] = tmp

    tmp = inv_sbox[state[3][0]]
    state[3][0] = inv_sbox[state[3][1]]
    state[3][1] = inv_sbox[state[3][2]]
    state[3][2] = inv_sbox[state[3][3]]
    state[3][3] = tmp

    return state

def mix_columns(state):


    for i in range(nb):

          # decryption
        s0 = Xtime14[state[0][i]] ^ Xtime11[state[1][i]] ^ Xtime13[state[2][i]] ^ Xtime9[state[3][i]]
        s1 = Xtime9[state[0][i]] ^ Xtime14[state[1][i]] ^ Xtime11[state[2][i]] ^ Xtime13[state[3][i]]
        s2 = Xtime13[state[0][i]] ^ Xtime9[state[1][i]] ^ Xtime14[state[2][i]] ^ Xtime11[state[3][i]]
        s3 = Xtime11[state[0][i]] ^ Xtime13[state[1][i]] ^ Xtime9[state[2][i]] ^ Xtime14[state[3][i]]

        state[0][i] = s0
        state[1][i] = s1
        state[2][i] = s2
        state[3][i] = s3

    return state


def key_expansion(key):
    """It makes list of RoundKeys for function AddRoundKey. All details 
    about algorithm is is in AES standard

    """

    key_symbols = [ord(symbol) for symbol in key]

    # CipherKey should contain 16 symbols to fill 4*4 table. If it's less
    # complement the key with "0x01"
    if len(key_symbols) < 4 * nk:
        for i in range(4 * nk - len(key_symbols)):
            key_symbols.append(0x01)
    elif len(key_symbols) > 4 * nk:
        key_symbols = key_symbols[:4*nk]

    # make ChipherKey(which is base of KeySchedule)
    key_schedule = [[] for i in range(4)]
    for r in range(4):
        for c in range(nk):
            key_schedule[r].append(key_symbols[r + 4 * c])

    # Continue to fill KeySchedule
    for col in range(nk, nb * (nr + 1)):  # col - column number
        if col % nk == 0:
            # take shifted (col - 1)th column...
            tmp = [key_schedule[row][col - 1] for row in range(1, 4)]
            tmp.append(key_schedule[0][col - 1])

            # change its elements using Sbox-table like in SubBytes...
            for j in range(len(tmp)):
                sbox_row = tmp[j] // 0x10
                sbox_col = tmp[j] % 0x10
                sbox_elem = sbox[16 * sbox_row + sbox_col]
                tmp[j] = sbox_elem

            # and finally make XOR of 3 columns
            for row in range(4):
                s = (key_schedule[row][col - 4]) ^ (tmp[row]) ^ (rcon[row][int(col / nk - 1)])
                key_schedule[row].append(s)

        else:
            # just make XOR of 2 columns
            for row in range(4):
                s = key_schedule[row][col - 4] ^ key_schedule[row][col - 1]
                key_schedule[row].append(s)
    #print('This is from AES256.')
    return key_schedule


def add_round_key(state, key_schedule, round=0):
    """That transformation combines State and KeySchedule together. Xor 
    of State and RoundSchedule(part of KeySchedule).

    """

    for col in range(4):
        # nb*round is a shift which indicates start of a part of the KeySchedule
        state[0][col] = state[0][col] ^ key_schedule[0][nb * round + col]
        state[1][col] = state[1][col] ^ key_schedule[1][nb * round + col]
        state[2][col] = state[2][col] ^ key_schedule[2][nb * round + col]
        state[3][col] = state[3][col] ^ key_schedule[3][nb * round + col]

    return state
```

(You may see it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VC6tjF3nq-gBoExE2KA6EzlrQFAkqgVC), too.)

Please help me.

Comment: Interesting endeavor, but in the end StackOverflow is not an online debugger. The best way to tackle this is to add a lot of logging statements, logging the intermediate states of a few runs and compare them against correct encryption and/or decryption using a known good implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.It's helpful.